# Get current line's text (where the caret is blinking) of richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I really need to get the contents of the line where the caret is blinking in a rich text box control. Suppose I have the following text in a rich text box:

```
This
is
a
test
```

I would like to retrieve the text of line 2 by providing its index (for example 2 or 1 if the function is zero-based).

Thanks in advance,

Vali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the question's title and what you really want to know are the same... If you want to get a line given its index, check the **Lines** property of the RichTextBox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the WordWrap for the text box set to false to make sure the index of the line corresponds to the line where the caret is.
Try this:

```
var pos = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Lines[pos]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
    richTextBox1.Lines[1]
```

Comment: That's the first line, not the selected line... and anyway he'd be better off using the `Lines` property.

Comment: Also, you should at least be using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`.